# Get random lon and lat coordinate dataset for given shape files from R

Tags: r, random, coordinates

I have a dataset, which has zone information and also a shapefile of the zone. How can I create random coordinate for a given zone for my dataset?

The data look like, as follows:

```
ID, Age, Gender, Income, Zone, Geomety
1, 20, M, 1000, A, POLYGON ((-0.09729 51.52158, -0.09652 51.52027...))
2, 30, F, 1000, B, POLYGON ((-0.08729 50.52158, -0.09652 51.52027...))
3, 37, F, 1000, C, POLYGON ((-0.07729 49.52158, -0.09652 51.52027...))
4, 45, M, 1000, D, POLYGON ((-0.06729 48.52158, -0.09652 51.52027...))
5, 20, F, 1000, A, POLYGON ((-0.09729 51.52158, -0.09652 51.52027...))
6, 43, M, 1000, B, POLYGON ((-0.08729 50.52158, -0.09652 51.52027...))
7, 37, F, 1000, C, POLYGON ((-0.07729 49.52158, -0.09652 51.52027...))
8, 26, M, 1000, D, POLYGON ((-0.06729 48.52158, -0.09652 51.52027...))
```

The expected result will be

```
 ID, Age, Gender, Income, Zone, Geomety, Point
        1, 20, M, 1000, A, POLYGON ((-0.09729 51.52158, -0.09652 51.52027...)), POINT((-0.09829 50.52158)
        2, 20, M, 1000, B, POLYGON ((-0.08729 50.52158, -0.09652 51.52027...)),POINT((-0.08929 50.52158)
        3, 20, M, 1000, C, POLYGON ((-0.07729 49.52158, -0.09652 51.52027...)),POINT((-0.07829 50.52158)
        4, 20, M, 1000, D, POLYGON ((-0.06729 48.52158, -0.09652 51.52027...)),POINT((-0.06829 50.52158)
        5, 20, M, 1000, A, POLYGON ((-0.09729 51.52158, -0.09652 51.52027...)),POINT((-0.09929 50.52158)
        6, 20, M, 1000, B, POLYGON ((-0.08729 50.52158, -0.09652 51.52027...)),POINT((-0.08929 50.52158)
        7, 20, M, 1000, C, POLYGON ((-0.07729 49.52158, -0.09652 51.52027...)),POINT((-0.079 50.52158)
        8, 20, M, 1000, D, POLYGON ((-0.06729 48.52158, -0.09652 51.52027...)),POINT((-0.06929 50.52158)
```

Comment: Does this help... https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280996/create-random-points-within-polygons-of-a-spatial-data-frame-in-r ?

Comment: without further information or sample data: read shapefile as simple feature, using the `sf`-package. Then use `sf::st_sample()` to get random points

Comment: Thank you.  I just added the illustration example. I tried that approach, and it seems not working for my cases.

Comment: Your `point` for `id == 1` doesn't seem to be part of `polygon`...